# AssertResultSetsHaveSameMetaData in TSQLT

Tags: tsqlt

I am using TSQLT AssertResultSetsHaveSameMetaData to compare metadata between two tables.But the problem is that i cannot hardcode the table name since i am passing the table name as the parameter at the runtime.So is there any way to do that

Answer (score 3):

You use `tSQLt.AssertResultSetsHaveSameMetaData` by passing two select statements like this:

```
exec tSQLt.AssertResultSetsHaveSameMetaData
      'SELECT TOP 1 * FROM mySchema.ThisTable;'
    , 'SELECT TOP 1 * FROM mySchema.ThatTable;';
```

So it should be quite easy to parameterise the names of the tables you are comparing and build the SELECT statements based on those table name parameters.

However, if you are using the latest version of tSQLt you can also now use `tSQLt.AssertEqualsTableSchema` to do the same thing.  You would use this assertion like this:

```
exec tSQLt.AssertEqualsTableSchema
      'mySchema.ThisTable'
    , 'mySchema.ThatTable';
```

Once again, parameterising the tables names would be easy since they are passed to `AssertEqualsTableSchema` as parameters.

If you explain the use case/context and provide sample code to explain what you are trying to do you stand a better chance of getting the help you need.